# How can I address the 'Mempool transaction rejected due to low fee' error when attempting to send a Bitcoin transaction with insufficient fees?

Tags: transactions

I've encountered a 'Mempool transaction rejected due to low fee' error while trying to send a Bitcoin transaction with a low fee. I'd like to understand how I can resolve this issue and successfully get my transaction processed despite the low fee.
Any guidance on adjusting fees or best practices in such situations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it). If your fee is below the minimum relay fee of peers then you probably need to instruct your wallet to discard the transaction and create a new one with a more suitable fee.